# Is there any feasible solution to split the components template into multiple parts in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component and it has different template-content based on the props value. I feel like the component's structure isn't good enough and it'll be really uncomfortable for any person to understand the code. How can I reduce the components into multiple divisions?

```html
<template>
<div>
    <div v-if='config.isTag'>
       <!-- some 10 lines of code -->
        <span 
            v-if="ok" 
            class="class">
        </span>
        <span v-else >
            <em>
            <!-- some 3 lines of code --></em>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div 
        v-if="ok"
        class='classes'>
        <div v-if="ok">
            <div v-if="ok" >
               <!-- some 20 lines of code -->
            </div>
            <div 
                v-else
                class="classes" 
                >
               <!-- some 40 lines of code -->
                <div 
                    class="class">
                    <!-- some 4 lines of code -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div 
            class="option-list" 
            >
            <div
                v-if="ok">
                 <!-- some 30 lines of code -->
            </div>
            <div 
                v-show='condition_ok'
                v-for="(data, i) in list"
                :key="i">
               <!-- some 40 lines of code -->
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div
</template>
```

So this is my template and it takes almost 200 lines of code..... Is there any possible way that I could make it shorter or I could have any template from multiple places and just import it if needed?

That is Splitting the components into multiple fragments.

Comment: You should think about your component splitting itself - is there repeatedly used code that could be put into an own component?
The new style guide also recommends creating components with a specific naming for components that aren't used multiple times. Example `TheHeader.vue`. https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Single-instance-component-names-strongly-recommended

Comment: @sandrooco I'm using some 15 lines of code repeated at two places.

Comment: That still makes 28 saved lines in your file. :)

Comment: I didn't reuse @sandrooco, why would I write separate components for juz a 15 lines of code?

Comment: Because you are asking for ways to make your file shorter. Check Ross' answer, it's basically what I meant.

Comment: @sandrooco yeah, I thought there would be some other solution to do so, but Ross' solution is by creating multiple components, so thereby to use common methods, I should write it with mixin, which makes the code more complex for a person to understand.... But I guess Ross' solution is the only way !

Comment: Mixins are for data related stuff, not markup. :) It's a cool feature though!

Answer (score 3):

It's not only possible, it's essential!

In your case, it could be done like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if='config.isTag'>
            <CustomComponentOne></CustomComponentOne>
        </div>
        <div v-if="ok"
            class='classes'>
                <CustomComponentTwo></CustomComponentTwo>
            <div class="option-list">
                <div v-if="ok">
                    <CustomComponentThree></CustomComponentThree>
                </div>
                <div v-show='condition_ok'
                    v-for="(data, i) in list"
                    :key="i">
                    <CustomComponentFour></CustomComponentFour>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import CustomComponentOne from '@/components/CustomComponentOne'
    import CustomComponentTwo from '@/components/CustomComponentTwo'
    import CustomComponentThree from '@/components/CustomComponentThree'
    import CustomComponentFour from '@/components/CustomComponentFour'

    export default {
        components: {
            CustomComponentOne,
            CustomComponentTwo,
            CustomComponentThree,
            CustomComponentFour
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Hey, @Ross Gaith so I could do this only with multiple components?

Comment: @VíñịtVịłłă Without looking at your code, I would say 'yes'; however, it's possible that your code could be refactored, which could then reduce it to the point where additional components is unnecessary.